# Cherry picking git commit SHAs back into a parent branch

Tags: git, github, merge

My git repo has a `master` and a `development` branch on the origin server (GitHub). I cut a feature branch from `development` and made **way** too many commits to it, and am left with a handful of commits that I *want* merged/added back to `development`, and a whole bunch of ones that I *don't want* added back in.

**Is this *possible* to do?** That is, if you have, say 50 commits on a feature branch, and only want to add, say, 8 of them back to a parent branch, can you cherry pick those 8 (if you know their commit SHAs) and add them in? If not, why? And if so, what's the magical git command to do so?

Comment: Read about [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you're asking.  I can say this even though the question is ambiguous; it just happens that there are a *different* many ways, depending on which result you're looking for.  One of those ways - the one you're baiting with the way you phrased your question - is the `cherry-pick` command.  But I don't recommend it because there are easier ways.

For example, in your case you can use `git rebase`.  You can look at `cherry-pick` as a special case of `rebase`, or you can look at `rebase` as a way to (among other things) automate a series of `cherry-pick`s.

In any case, as a smaller/more easily shown example, say you start with

```
x -- o -- x -- x <--(master)
      \
       A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J <--(branch)
```

and you want to keep just three commits, which correspond in some way to `B`, `G`, and `J`.

Now I say "correspond in some way" because there are two ways to look at "only keeping certain commits".  Suppose at `o` you have some files, including a directory `foo` containing the file `o`.  And suppose that each commit `A` through `J` adds a file to `foo`; `A` adds `foo/A`, `B` adds `foo/B`, etc. 
 Therefore at commit `G`, for example, you have a `TREE` that includes `foo/o`, `foo/A`, `foo/B`, `foo/C`, `foo/D`, `foo/E`, `foo/F`, and `foo/G`.

(In general, of course, each commit might edit one or more files; but the difference I'm asking about is easiest to illustrate if each commit just creates a separate file.  The principle is the same either way, as long as you realize that "edit a file", to git, means "add some lines, delete some lines, change some lines").

Now at a fundamental level, a commit in git is a snapshot of the entire content.  So "keep commits `B`, `G`, and `J` could mean you want

```
x -- o -- x -- x <--(master)
      \
       AB -- CDEFG -- HIJ <--(branch)
```

where `AB` has a tree containing `foo/A` and `foo/B`; and `CDEFG` has a `TREE` containing `foo/A`, `foo/B`, `foo/C`, `foo/D`, `foo/E`, `foo/F`, and `foo/G`; etc.

A lot of people think of a commit as a set of *changes* - i.e. the patch that would convert the commit's parent's `TREE` into the commit's `TREE`.  Even though git as a whole doesn't work that way, `rebase` does treat commits in much that way.  So if you think that way, maybe you want

```
x -- o -- x -- Z <--(master)
      \
       B' -- G' -- J' <--(branch)
```

where `B'` makes the same *changes* relative to `o` as `B` had made relative to `A`.  That would mean that `B'` has a `TREE` with `foo/B` (but not `foo/A`); and `G'` has a `TREE` with `foo/B` and `foo/G`; etc.

Either way, an interactive rebase will do the job.  It'll create the new, fewer commits that you want, and move `branch` to refer to them; and you can proceed from there.

If you want to keep the branch based at `o`, you might do something like

```
git rebase -i `git merge-base master branch` branch
```

It would be simpler to say

```
git rebase -i master branch
```

which will still operate on the correct set of commits; the difference is that the latter command will make the first "new" commit's parent `Z` instead of `o`.

Whichever command you issue will bring up a text editor with a TODO list containing an entry for each commit from `A` through `J`.  Each entry starts with the command `pick` by default.  We'll change some of those commands.

If you want commits like `AB`, `CDEFG`, and `HIJ`, then you'll use the command `squash`.  This says to combine the patch for a commit with the patch for the one before it.  So you'd change the commands for `B` (to combine `B` with `A` yielding `AB`), `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G` (to get `CDEFG`), and `I` and `J`.

On the other hand, if you just want `B'`, `G'`, and `J'`, then you would use the `drop` command (or just remove the unwanted commits from the `TODO` list).  You would change the lines for `A`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `H`, and `I`.

As I noted, this is just one of several ways.  At its core git is a content storage system that's well suited (specialized even) to storing a project history.  It's very flexible in how it lets you modify the content, though it does try to protect against any potentially-accidental *loss* of content.